# Who are the parents of Indra and Brahma mentioned by Basava?

Tags: brahma, indra, shaivism

The term "Shaivite" is overused nowadays. For instance, Iyer Brahmins are often called Shaivites, but they're actually followers of Adi Shankaracharya's Smartha sect (which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3796/36) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2480/36)) and simply adopt Shiva as their Ishta Devata. True philosophical Shaivism is relatively rare nowadays (in contrast to Vaishnavism which is pretty common). Now one genuine Shaivite sect is the Lingayat sect, which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6621/36).  It was founded by the 12th century philosopher Basava.

Now in one of his Vachanas or poems, Basava says [this](https://books.google.co.in/books/content?id=kITXAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA204&img=1&pgis=1&dq=indra+amritavati&sig=ACfU3U1uJPic-9wS0VzUl-c03mKNxjeodw&edge=0) in an attempt to prove that Shiva is supreme:

> **Indra was born to Amritavati and Somasambhu**
>   **Brahma was bom to Satyarishi and Jyesthadevi** 
>   Visnu born to Vasudeva and Devaki 
>  
>   The Enlightened was born to Nabhiraj and Marutadevi 
>   All known to the worlds as fashioned out of the womb 
>   Has Lord Kudalasangamadeva, who lives outside 
>   The cycle of birth and death 
>   Any father and mother?

Some of these are recognizable: Vasudeva and Devaki are the parents of Vishnu's incarnation Krishna, and Nabhiraj and Marutadevi are the parents of Rishabha the founder of Jainism.  But my question is, who are Amritavati, Somashambhu, Satyarishi, and Jyeshthadevi, the parents of Indra and Brahma mentioned by Basava?

Note that I'm not actually asking who Indra and Brahma's parents are.  Indra's parents are Kashyapa and Aditi, and Brahma's father is Vishnu, or Vishnu's Vyuha form Aniruddha to be more precise.  But I want to know who the figures are mentioned by Basava.  Are there any scriptures that mention them in connection to Indra and Brahma?

Comment: Are there any Iyers who adopt Vishnu as their Ishta?

Comment: *term "Shaivite" is overused* in what sense? I didn't understand why u said that.

Comment: @Secret Overused in the sense that it's used for people who are not actual Shaivites.

Comment: " not actual Shaivite" means?

Comment: @Secret Meaning they don't view Shiva as supreme, or they don't base their belief system on the Shaiva Agamas, etc.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Yes, there are a small number of Iyers who have Vishnu as their Ishta Devata.  Originally most Advaitins had Vishnu as their Ishta Devata, but it changed to Shiva over time.  Kanchi Mahaperiyava, the former Shankaracharya of Kanchipuram, explains the reason for this shift in this interview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2kAQ.jpg